# is there any way to get title of the pdf file direct iterating from pdf paragraphs and not from metadata?

Tags: python-3.x, pdf

I want to get the title in output when i pass the pdf file as input using python code.

I have used pdfreader, pypdf2, pdfminer libraries but all fetches the title from metadata.

Is there anyway to get the title directly from pdf paragraphs info?

Comment: @KJ THANK YOU for your valuable suggestions. i got the solution please review my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help.

I found the solution from pdfminer library.

```
from pdfminer.high_level import extract_pages
from pdfminer.layout import LTTextContainer, LTChar,LTLine,LAParams
import os
path=r'/path/to/pdf'

Extract_Data=[]

for page_layout in extract_pages(path):
    for element in page_layout:
        if isinstance(element, LTTextContainer):
            for text_line in element:
                for character in text_line:
                    if isinstance(character, LTChar):
                        Font_size=character.size
            Extract_Data.append([Font_size,(element.get_text())])

title = (max(Extract_Data))
print(title[1])
```